# Trying to submit a form from a link while calling a function at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I submit a form from a link, it should submit the form and at the same time onsubmit it should call a function.

Is it possible to achieve this?

```html
<form  id=abc>
  <input type=hidden id=qty  name=quantity value=1 title=Qty/>
</form>
<a onclick=document.getElementById('abc').submit();>
  <h1>Click Me</h1>
</a>
<script>  
  document.getElementById("abc").onsubmit = function()
  {
    test22()
  };
    
  function test22(){
    alert('aaa');
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you should try this

```
<form  id=abc>
  <input type=hidden id=qty  name=quantity value=1 title=Qty/>
</form>

<a onclick="submit_form()">
  <h1>Click Me</h1>
</a>

<script>  
  function submit_form(){
    document.getElementById("abc").submit();
  }

  document.getElementById("abc").onsubmit = function(){
    test22()
  };

  function test22(){
    alert('aaa');
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

or simply

```
 <script>  
  function submit_form(){
    document.getElementById("abc").submit();
      test22();
    }

  function test22(){
    alert('aaa');
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

INLINE JAVASCRIPT IS NOT RECOMMENDED

but you could do this

```
<form  onsubmit="test22();" id=abc>
  <input type=hidden id=qty  name=quantity value=1 title=Qty/>
</form>
```